# Using ESLint with astrojs react - import/no-unresolved

Tags: reactjs, eslint, astrojs

I'm new to using Astro and installed react using

```
npx astro add react
```

ESLint using

```
npm init @eslint/config
```

and the following Astro plugins:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-astro
npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/parser
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
```

The issue is in my `astro.config.mjs` file with this line:

```
import react from '@astrojs/react';
```

Where **@astrojs/react** has the ESLint issue

```
Unable to resolve the path to module '@astrojs/react'.eslintimport/no-unresolved
```

My **.eslintrc.cjs** file is the following

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:astro/recommended',
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.astro'],
      parser: 'astro-eslint-parser',
      parserOptions: {
        parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
        extraFileExtensions: ['.astro'],
      },
      rules: {},
    },
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {},
};
```

I appreciate the help.